# hybrid ultrabook: install ubuntu on ssd keeping win8

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, ssd

I have the following configuration on a asus vivobook, with hdd+ssd: [image]http://snag.gy/4Uq1b.jpg

Disk 0 is 500gb hdd, disk1 is 24 gb ssd.
I would like to keep the existing win8 installation, installing ubuntu in dual boot. 
Is it possible to install it on the 18 gb partition of SSD, without losing the possibility to boot on win8?
Have I to put there alse the swap (I am going to use very often the stand-by funcion)?

In order to optimize SSD, I planned to put /home, /tmp and /var on a suitable partition of hdd.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot into Windows and disable the [**Intel Smart Response Technology**](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/sb/CS-032826.htm). Now your SSD is no longer used to accelerate Windows 8.

Now do whatever you want with the SSD.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. It was not the right one, indeed, but it put me on the right direction: ASUS does not come with IRT, but it uses the SSD to cache system files. I disabled that option and now I have ubuntu running from ssd and windows 8 still working.